# За счет чего создается отличие скорости именованных каналов от сокетов?

Tags: сокет, tcp

Прочитал в объяснение такую фразу

> Именованные каналы дают вам возможность отправлять данные без потери
> производительности, связанной с привлечением сетевого стека.

Не могу понять что значит "привлечением сетевого стека" в случае с сокетами, т.е. если у меня открыт сокет между двумя процессами на одном сервере то пакеты идут все равно как то через сетевую карту и т.п. ?

Comment: Не через сетевую карту, но всё равно появляются накладные расходы на обработку IP-адресов (даже если это 127.0.0.1), маршрутизацию и обработку TCP-соединений - всякая ненужная шелуха, в общем

Comment: Я думаю есть смысл отетить один из ответов зелёной галочкой, или дать обратную связь чем не нравится ответы, и уточнить вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, даже если сокеты открыты на одном сервере - то создаются структуры, которые поддерживают соединение. Такие, как счетчики пакетов, "окно TCP" и т.п.

При этом пакеты не идут "через сетевую карту", но при кажой процедуре записи в сокет происходит некая работа, которая происходит при работе с сетевыми сокетами и работа происходит с теми же структурами данных и объектами ядра, что и при работе с "настоящей сетью"

При использовании именованных каналов у Вас создаются только структуры, примерно соовтетствующие "файлу", причём, созданному в памяти. Собственно, named pipes примерно соответствует своему названию: это "труба", куда оба связанных процессам могут писать и откуда могут читать.

Вообще говоря, сетевой стек - это очень производительная вещь, и часто, ради того, чтобы код был единообразен для работы локально и "через сеть", вполне допустимо использовать сетевые соединения как универсальный способ связи.

Особенно в этом смысле хвалят сетевой стек FreeBSD - это не относится к вопросу, но просто к слову пришлось :-)

Comment: Спасибо! Посоветуйте книгу где можно более фундаментально все почитать? (счетчики пакетов, "окно TCP" и т.п.)

Comment: Уже не первый раз на этом сайте - советую книжку У. Р. Стивенса "UNIX. Разработка сетевых приложений". Книжке не меньше 20 лет, но она до сих пор очень актуальна. Книжка без собых проблем гуглится. Если не получится найти - напишите еще раз, что нить придумаем! Конкретно про вот эту штуку - TCP и т.п. - написано в пятой главе.

Comment: скорей всего в цитате имеются в виду именованные каналы windows... вряд ли кто-то в здравом уме будет советовать использовать nix'овые трубы вместо сокетов...

Comment: Да изначально по win речь шла. А почему в nix это по другому?

Comment: @S.H., действительно хорошая книжка. (в результате поставил себе FB2 читалку, единственно работающим  в моем Mint оказался  fbreader)

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, это просто достаточно разные примитивы: *nix'овые именованные каналы — это однонаправленные трубы, с которыми на практике достаточно много проблем, так что они обычно используются или в скриптах или в специфических случаях на грани хака… а в win — это дуплексный примитив, который к тому же может устанавливать соединения... это скорее аналог сокетов домена `AF_UNIX`… Плюс я не замерял и не так хорошо знаком с win, но этот совет скорее более релевантен для него с его реализацией tcp/ip в юзерспейсе, чем для bsd/linux'ов…

Comment: @ПавелКозлов, ЗЫ: если ожидаешь ответа в комментариях, цитируй ник через `@собаку`

Answer (score 2):

Для работы pipe ничего дополнительно не нужно. Поддержка pipe зашита в ядро и довольно хорошо там оптимизирована. (Для win-NT-семейства это ntdll.dll для более старых win95/98 и т п это был kernel32.dll). Локальный pipe представляет собой просто тупо кусок памяти куда можно читать/писать информацию.

В windows библиотека сокета - отдельная, состоит из двух частей, клиентской dll например wsock32.dll (но есть и другие клиентские либы), которая загружает драйвер, и операции с сокетом реализованы в драйвере. При загруке библиотеки сокета - я сталкивался с тем, что некоторые антивирусы начинают проверять вашу программу усиленно на наличие вируса, и даже могут заблокировать её работу. Т.е. при открытии сокета - загружается клиентская либа. Потом загружается драйвер. Так как есть несколько видов сокета - подгружаются различные фильтры-обработчики. Обращение на чтение/запись - передаётся клиентской библиотеке. Клиентская библиотека переформатирует запрос, и отправляет в драйвер. А уже драйвер делает операции у себя внутри. Поэтому передача допустим 1024 байт по сокету и по pipe будет для сокета занимать больше тактов ЦП, возможно даже в 10 раз больше, точно сказать сложно во сколько, но больше это точно.